# how can i model this on uml diagram in this case

Tags: c#, uml

I'm using staruml modeling tool but I'm new to modeling in UML.
While I made a simple C# code and converted this code to UML I hit a road blocking. How should I express below code in UML:

```
public static IDataLayer GetInstance()
{``
    DatabaseTypes dbType = ConvertDBType(GetAppConfigSettings());
    return GetInstance(dbtype, GetAppConfigSettings(Constants.AppConfigurationString, true),
                            GetAppConfigSettings(Constants.AppConfiguration, false) != false.ToString());
}
```

There is another operation(function) inside an operation (procedure).

Answer (score 1):

This is a behavior aspect of the model. Your class will only show the method and its return type. When you create a collaboration with a sequence diagram later in the design process you can show that the method call will issue an internal call to another object method.